# ¿Cómo identificar una fecha no establecida?

Tags: c#, mysql

Saludos a todos tengo un problema que es el siguiente, en la empresa dónde estoy trabajando la identificación de fecha no es un formato como tal, 80301 
algo así sería dónde el 8 es el año, 03 el mes, y 01 el día...

Cómo podría trabajarlo para identificar datos por día?

Gracias

Comment: Por lo que describes tendrás que trabajar con la cadena que estás recuperando del servidor y realizar una transformacion de `string` a `DateTime` Fuente; https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/standard/base-types/parsing-datetime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  String fechaRara = "80301";

        String ano = fechaRara.Substring(0, 1);//8
        String mes = fechaRara.Substring(1, 2);//03
        String dia = fechaRara.Substring(3, 2);//01

        DateTime fecha = DateTime.Parse(dia + "/" + mes + "/"  + "201" + ano);
```

Pues esto funcionaria, pero solo tomando en cuenta que el día y mes siempre tienen dos dígitos y que el año 8 es 2018

No es un código que me guste mucho... pero tampoco me gusta mucho ese formato jajajaja

Comment: Muchas Gracias, si resolví mi problema.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes hacerlo asi:

```
        int dia = DateTime.ParseExact("80301".PadLeft(6,'0')/*esto es por si el año viene de 1 solo digito*/
                , "yyMMdd", null, DateTimeStyles.None).Day;//el .day puede variar dependiendo de lo que necesites month o year
```

espero te sirva!

Comment: En mi opinión esta debería ser la respuesta aceptada. Enhorabuena